Нет доступа к системной информации python
Имеется скрипт на пайтон, который находится в одной папке с dll библиотекой. Скрипт должен собирать информацию о параметрах системы, таких как температура ГП, ЦП, загрузка ОЗУ и прочее, но походу система блочит получение данных cpu_temp, gpu_temp и rpm. Данные дальше отправляются через блютуз на устройство, которое их выводит на дисплей. Помогите как решить проблему с доступом к данным
В коде используются модули psutil, pythonnet, pyserial
import serial
import os
import time
import clr
import psutil

updateTime = 4 # number of seconds between each update

hardwaretypes = ['Mainboard','SuperIO','CPU','RAM','GpuNvidia','GpuAti','TBalancer','Heatmaster','HDD']
sensortypes = ['Voltage','Clock','Temperature','Load','Fan','Flow','Control','Level','Factor','Power','Data','SmallData']

cpu_temp = ''
rpm = ''
gpu_temp = ''

def sendData(temp, rpm, gpu, free_disk, free_mem, procs):
    try:
        connection = serial.Serial('COM7')
        data = temp + ',' + rpm + ',' + str(free_mem) + ',' + str(free_disk) + ',' + gpu + ',' + str(procs) + '/'
        connection.write(data.encode())
        print("Data written", data.encode())
        connection.close  
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def initialize_openhardwaremonitor():
    file = 'OpenHardwareMonitorLib'
    clr.AddReference(file)

    from OpenHardwareMonitor import Hardware

    handle = Hardware.Computer()
    handle.MainboardEnabled = True
    handle.CPUEnabled = True
    handle.RAMEnabled = True
    handle.GPUEnabled = True
    handle.Open()
    return handle

def fetch_stats(handle):
    for i in handle.Hardware:
        i.Update()
        for sensor in i.Sensors:
            parse_sensor(sensor)
        for j in i.SubHardware:
            j.Update()
            for subsensor in j.Sensors:
                parse_sensor(subsensor)

def parse_sensor(sensor):
        global cpu_temp
        global rpm
        global gpu_temp
        if sensor.Value is not None:
            if sensor.SensorType == sensortypes.index('Temperature') and sensor.Name == 'CPU Package':
                cpu_temp = str(int(sensor.Value))

            if sensor.SensorType == sensortypes.index('Fan') and sensor.Name == 'Fan #1':
                rpm = str(int(sensor.Value))

            if sensor.SensorType == sensortypes.index('Temperature') and sensor.Name == 'GPU Core':
               gpu_temp = str(int(sensor.Value))

HardwareHandle = initialize_openhardwaremonitor()

while(1):
    fetch_stats(HardwareHandle)
    obj_Disk = psutil.disk_usage('c:\\') # Drive letter with double \\
    free_disk = int(obj_Disk.free / (1024.0 ** 3))
    free_mem = (int((psutil.virtual_memory().total - psutil.virtual_memory().used)/ (1024 * 1024))) 
    proc_counter = 0
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        proc_counter += 1
    sendData(cpu_temp, rpm, gpu_temp, free_disk, free_mem, proc_counter)
    time.sleep(updateTime)


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Попробуйте запуск от имени администратора https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212512/Запуск-кода-от-имени-администратора
